# Rendered attribute not rendering rich panel on value change listener

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2

I am developing an application using JSF 1.2 (sun RI) and richFaces 3.3.

I want to display a panel when a list value is changed in select list,below the select list.

Following is the code for the same :

```
> <a4j:form ajaxSubmit="true">              
>          
 <h:panelGrid id="videoServiceTab">                                     <h:outputLabel for="deviceSelect" value="Select Device :"/>                       
>               
>               <h:selectOneMenu id="deviceId" value="#{deviceBean.deviceId}" valueChangeListener="#{deviceBean.startLiveStream}">
>                   <f:selectItems  value="#{deviceBean.userDevices}"/>
>                   <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="videoPanel" />
>               </h:selectOneMenu>                                          
>               <rich:panel id="videoPanel" rendered="#{deviceBean.showPane}">
>                   My Panel..  
>               </rich:panel>                                                </h:panelGrid>   
</a4j:form>
```

1)When a list value is selected , valueChangeListener is called , which updates the showPane value in a method (sets to true , default value is false)

2)But even though showPane value is set to true , rich panel is not getting displayed.

3)Following is the log , with jsf's "PhaseListener" incorporated,it clearly indicates that , before "RENDER_RESPONSE" is completed , showPane value is set to true
Still rich panel with id videoPanel is not getting displayed.

4)The backing bean (deviceBean) is request scoped.

-------------log for phase listener ----------

START PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3

is show pane called..false

inside startLiveStream

returning from service method..

END PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3

START PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4

is show pane called..true

END PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4

START PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5

END PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5

START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6

is show pane called..true

is show pane called..true

END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6

Comment: It should work just with a normal `h:form`. Have you tried other options like removing `panelGrid`? It looks like JSF is not finding the id of the component to reRender.. Is it displaying if you refresh the page in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I tried following code and it worked. As evident from documentation of a4j:outputPanel,it wraps the component which needs to be updated/modified , which is true for panelGrid as shown below

```
<a4j:outputPanel layout="none">
    <h:panelGrid id="videoPanel" rendered="#{deviceBean.showPane}">
    Display Panel..
                                            </h:panelGrid>      
    </a4j:outptPanel>
```